# Drupal 8 twig multiple images field

Tags: drupal, twig, field, drupal-8, multiple-value

I have a content type with a field **field_gallery** that has **multiple images**.
I would like to get all these images printed in my twig file: **page--front.html.twig**. So i want to get these images in my frontpage and not only in their nodes. So far i could get them in their nodes with

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

but not somewhere else (of course since its using node). Is this possible?

Should i create a preprocessor function for page? Any guidance for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible. This question is have two sub tasks :

**1) Creating page--front.html.twig file**
For creation of this twig file, you'll have to clone file i.e. page.html.twig and rename it with page--front.html.twig

**2) Fetch Raw values of Image fields**
You need to update code in my .theme file:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['node']->field_image->entity) {
      $variables['image_url'] = $url = entity_load('image_style', 'medium')->buildUrl($variables['node']->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
  }
}
```

Then in page--front.html.twig file I have this:

```
{% for item in image_url %}
  <div class="featured-thumb">
        <img src="{{ item }}"/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you replaced "field_image" with your field's machine name ?